# Ошибки Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: javascript

В HTML существует форма с именем `regform`. Также имеется обработчик на JavaScript:

```
document.regform.onsubmit = function() {
  var error = document.getElementById('error');
  if (document.regform.name.value == "") {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Вы забыли ввести имя";
    document.regform.name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.sername.value == "") {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Вы забыли ввести Фамилию";
    document.regform.sername.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.pass.value == "") {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Вы забыли ввести пароль";
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;

  }
  if (document.regform.pass.value.length < 6) {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов";
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.regform.pass.value.length > 20) {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 20 символов";
    document.regform.password.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (document.regform.email.value == "") {
    error.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerHTML = "Вы забыли ввести Email";
    document.regform.email.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Выдается ошибка:

> Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of undefined

---

Как `document.regform` определить?

Comment: плюсую Алекса, хоть бы в translate.google.com ошибку перевел

Comment: А данная ошибка проявляется во всех броузерах (FireFox/Opera/MSIE/etc..) ?

Comment: Да ошибка во всех браузерах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас добавление `onsubmit` происходит в теге  `script` секции `head`, а `form` в `body`. Следовательно, нужно сделать так, чтобы прописывание `onsubmit` происходило после полного построения DOM или чтобы скрипт был ниже тега `form`, например:

```
<form name="regform">
  ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.regform.onsubmit = 
    ...
</script>
```

Для контроля загрузки DOM, можно либо использовать JQuery, либо проверенным способом:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        document.regform.onsubmit = ...
    }
</script>
...
</head>
<body onload="init">
```

---

Событие `DOMContentLoaded` происходит когда весь HTML был полностью загружен и пройден парсером, не дожидаясь окончания загрузки таблиц стилей, изображений и фреймов.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

Comment: Спасибо бро)Помогло)

Comment: Вот я не пойму - к чему и тут было приплетено JQuery?

Comment: Для контроля загрузки DOM, можно использовать JQuery:

    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(
                function () {
                     document.regform.onsubmit = ...
                }
            );
        </script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <form name="regform">
            ...
        </form>
        ...
    </body>

Comment: Для контроля загрузки DOM можно использовать практически любой javascript фреймворк, например dojo, prototype, ext и т.д.

И это кагбы понятно по определению, я просто реально не понимаю к чему тут было упоминать JQuery... 

Привидите тогда примеры для всех популярных фреймворков, а то выглядит так, как будто столь "великие" вещи подвласны исключительно "великому" jquery ;)

У вас просто написано - либо так либо JQuery, как будто-бы - альтернатив - нет

Comment: Фраза звучит, как /использовать JQuery или .../ то что подобное можно сделать на любом другом удобном фреймвоке нет ни каких сомнений, так же как и все приведенные мною примере в ответе не используют jq

Answer (score 2):

"Может" потому, что:

```
 document.regform === undefined
```

Comment: Как document.regform сделать не undefined?

Comment: В html добавьте форме атрибут `name="regform"`, либо воспользуйтесь вариантом который предложил @ling

Могу предположить что у вас прописан `name` для формы и вы просто выполняете ваш javascript код не на событии `onload`

Любой код работающий с html элементами должен отрабатывать на событии загрузки страницы, т.е.:

     onload = function(){
           // и уже тут ваш код...
     }

Answer (score 0):

Задайте форме `id = "regform"`, а потом выбирайте ее через `var form = document.getElementById("regform");`.